# Can't login to Game Center sandbox, used to work

Tags: ios, game-center

I am getting the following error when login into Game Center sandbox environment:

.

[image]

...with the following message in the terminal:

```
<Error>: CGImageCreate: invalid image size: 0 x 0.
```

I have been trying to find a solution but do not know what to do. It used to work.

Comment: It works for me too now, i guess it has something to do with iTunes but still why that error message?

Answer (score 0):

I am receiving exactly the same error, to verify it was not my code I used a sample code by Erica Sadun (Author iPhone Developers Cookbook) and had the same error.

I hope this does nor continue through the iTunes Connect shutdown.

UPDATE******
Now appears to be working but very slow..